# Implementation of a TDC in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm attempting to implement a Time to Digital Converter (TDC) in System Verilog. So far I've attempted 2 different methods and not sure if either has been successful.

The First Method is based on the following diagram
[image]

'''

```
module TDC #(
  parameter bits = 8
)(
  input logic start,
  input logic progate_stop,
  input logic reset,
  output logic [bits-1:0] comb_output
);

logic comb_one, comb_two, comb_three, comb_four, comb_five, comb_six, comb_seven, comb_eight;
logic pipo_one, pipo_two, pipo_three, pipo_four, pipo_five, pipo_six, pipo_seven, pipo_eight;


always_comb begin
  comb_one = start;
  comb_two = ~comb_one;
  comb_three = ~comb_two;
  comb_four = ~comb_three;
  comb_five = ~comb_four;
  comb_six = ~comb_five;
  comb_seven = ~comb_six;
  comb_eight = ~comb_seven;

end

always_ff@(progate_stop) begin
  if (reset ) begin
    pipo_one <= 1'b0;
    pipo_two <= 1'b0;
    pipo_three <= 1'b0;
    pipo_four <= 1'b0;
    pipo_five <= 1'b0;
    pipo_six <= 1'b0;
    pipo_seven <= 1'b0;
    pipo_eight <= 1'b0;
  end else begin

    pipo_one <= comb_one;
    pipo_two <= comb_two;
    pipo_three <= comb_three;
    pipo_four <= comb_four;
    pipo_five <= comb_five;
    pipo_six <= comb_six;
    pipo_seven <= comb_seven;
    pipo_eight <= comb_eight;
  end
end

always_comb begin
  comb_output[0] = pipo_one;
  comb_output[1] = ~pipo_two;
  comb_output[2] = pipo_three;
  comb_output[3] = ~pipo_four;
  comb_output[4] = pipo_five;
  comb_output[5] = ~pipo_six;
  comb_output[6] = pipo_seven;
  comb_output[7] = ~pipo_eight;
end

endmodule
```

The second method is based on the following diagram:
[image]

```
module TDC (
output reg [7:0] out     ,  // Output of the counter
input  wire      enable  ,  // enable for counter
input  wire      clk     ,  // clock Input
input  wire      reset,      // reset Input
input logic start,
input logic stop
);
//-------------Code Starts Here-------
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  
  if (reset) begin
    out <= 8'b0 ;
  end else begin
    if (start && !stop) begin
      out <= out+1;
    end else begin
      out <=out;
    end
  end

end

endmodule
```

Any advice on either of these would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advanc

Comment: You have no "time" in either of your models; no gate-delays or specify blocks.
Neither is going to do what you expect...

Answer (score -1):

a TDC is very dependant on the underlying technology that you are using. Although it is a "digital" block (in the sense that you use digital gates and flops to implement it), the reality is that in order to obtain accurate timings, you need to carefully lay out the gates and the flops, so typically you will need:

a) describe the circuit structurally, using the cells available in your ASIC library/FPGA
b) carefully lay out the elements so that TDC timing measurements are accurate.

In other words, writing behavioural RTL as you're doing is not going to achieve what you want, sorry.